# Uploading vector files in Open Street Maps

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to automate editings in OSM. 
I have shapefiles of an area of interest that has almost no information in OSM about it. Is there a way to upload these vector files that I have into OSM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is not recommended to upload Shapefiles to the OSM database. What you can do, is to use those shapefiles, as a base, to make edits which meet the topological requirements of OSM. Also note that copyright of these files ***should allow*** the usage of data in this way.

To get more information on this, read this document on the OSM wiki: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software_comparison/Import_a_shapefile

Comment: You said "use those SHP as a base to make edits" 
How will I do that? Is there any plugin that I can edit from QGIS?

Comment: @MatheusSiqueiraBarros The linked Page talks about how you can use the OpenData Plugin for JSOM (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/OpenData)

Comment: Also read the [import guidelines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines) and [automated edits code of conduct](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Automated_Edits_code_of_conduct). tl;dr: Don't do it.